# How could I get the amount scrolled through the section?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a web app and I'm making it so you cant scroll through the body or html so you don't constantly toggle and hide the address bar on mobile and the only div / thing you can scroll through is this section. How could I get (with pure js) the amount a user has scrolled through that section?

Here is demo code below:-

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: arial;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #212121;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  background: #111;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
}

section {
  overflow-Y: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}


h2, p {padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Random text</h1></header>
<section>
  <h2>Him boisterous invitation dispatched had connection inhabiting projection</h2>

  <p>Remain valley who mrs uneasy remove wooded him you. Her questions favourite him concealed. We to wife face took he. The taste begin early old why since dried can first. Prepared as or humoured formerly. Evil mrs true get post. Express village evening
    prudent my as ye hundred forming. Thoughts she why not directly reserved packages you. Winter an silent favour of am tended mutual.</p>

  <p>Shot what able cold new the see hold. Friendly as an betrayed formerly he. Morning because as to society behaved moments. Put ladies design mrs sister was. Play on hill felt john no gate. Am passed figure to marked in. Prosperous middletons is ye inhabiting
    as assistance me especially. For looking two cousins regular amongst.</p>

  <p>Sportsman delighted improving dashwoods gay instantly happiness six. Ham now amounted absolute not mistaken way pleasant whatever. At an these still no dried folly stood thing. Rapid it on hours hills it seven years. If polite he active county in spirit
    an. Mrs ham intention promotion engrossed assurance defective. Confined so graceful building opinions whatever trifling in. Insisted out differed ham man endeavor expenses. At on he total their he songs. Related compact effects is on settled do.</p>

  <p>Of on affixed civilly moments promise explain fertile in. Assurance advantage belonging happiness departure so of. Now improving and one sincerity intention allowance commanded not. Oh an am frankness be necessary earnestly advantage estimable extensive.
    Five he wife gone ye. Mrs suffering sportsmen earnestly any. In am do giving to afford parish settle easily garret.</p>

  <p>Literature admiration frequently indulgence announcing are who you her. Was least quick after six. So it yourself repeated together cheerful. Neither it cordial so painful picture studied if. Sex him position doubtful resolved boy expenses. Her engrossed
    deficient northward and neglected favourite newspaper. But use peculiar produced concerns ten.</p>

  <p>By spite about do of do allow blush. Additions in conveying or collected objection in. Suffer few desire wonder her object hardly nearer. Abroad no chatty others my silent an. Fat way appear denote who wholly narrow gay settle. Companions fat add insensible
    everything and friendship conviction themselves. Theirs months ten had add narrow own.</p>

  <p>On no twenty spring of in esteem spirit likely estate. Continue new you declared differed learning bringing honoured. At mean mind so upon they rent am walk. Shortly am waiting inhabit smiling he chiefly of in. Lain tore time gone him his dear sure.
    Fat decisively estimating affronting assistance not. Resolve pursuit regular so calling me. West he plan girl been my then up no.</p>

  <p>Put all speaking her delicate recurred possible. Set indulgence inquietude discretion insensible bed why announcing. Middleton fat two satisfied additions. So continued he or commanded household smallness delivered. Door poor on do walk in half. Roof
    his head the what.</p>

  <p>Continual delighted as elsewhere am convinced unfeeling. Introduced stimulated attachment no by projection. To loud lady whom my mile sold four. Need miss all four case fine age tell. He families my pleasant speaking it bringing it thoughts. View busy
    dine oh in knew if even. Boy these along far own other equal old fanny charm. Difficulty invitation put introduced see middletons nor preference.</p>

  <h2>Him boisterous invitation dispatched had connection inhabiting projection</h2>

  <p>Remain valley who mrs uneasy remove wooded him you. Her questions favourite him concealed. We to wife face took he. The taste begin early old why since dried can first. Prepared as or humoured formerly. Evil mrs true get post. Express village evening
    prudent my as ye hundred forming. Thoughts she why not directly reserved packages you. Winter an silent favour of am tended mutual.</p>

  <p>Shot what able cold new the see hold. Friendly as an betrayed formerly he. Morning because as to society behaved moments. Put ladies design mrs sister was. Play on hill felt john no gate. Am passed figure to marked in. Prosperous middletons is ye inhabiting
    as assistance me especially. For looking two cousins regular amongst.</p>

  <p>Sportsman delighted improving dashwoods gay instantly happiness six. Ham now amounted absolute not mistaken way pleasant whatever. At an these still no dried folly stood thing. Rapid it on hours hills it seven years. If polite he active county in spirit
    an. Mrs ham intention promotion engrossed assurance defective. Confined so graceful building opinions whatever trifling in. Insisted out differed ham man endeavor expenses. At on he total their he songs. Related compact effects is on settled do.</p>

  <p>Of on affixed civilly moments promise explain fertile in. Assurance advantage belonging happiness departure so of. Now improving and one sincerity intention allowance commanded not. Oh an am frankness be necessary earnestly advantage estimable extensive.
    Five he wife gone ye. Mrs suffering sportsmen earnestly any. In am do giving to afford parish settle easily garret.</p>

  <p>Literature admiration frequently indulgence announcing are who you her. Was least quick after six. So it yourself repeated together cheerful. Neither it cordial so painful picture studied if. Sex him position doubtful resolved boy expenses. Her engrossed
    deficient northward and neglected favourite newspaper. But use peculiar produced concerns ten.</p>

  <p>By spite about do of do allow blush. Additions in conveying or collected objection in. Suffer few desire wonder her object hardly nearer. Abroad no chatty others my silent an. Fat way appear denote who wholly narrow gay settle. Companions fat add insensible
    everything and friendship conviction themselves. Theirs months ten had add narrow own.</p>

  <p>On no twenty spring of in esteem spirit likely estate. Continue new you declared differed learning bringing honoured. At mean mind so upon they rent am walk. Shortly am waiting inhabit smiling he chiefly of in. Lain tore time gone him his dear sure.
    Fat decisively estimating affronting assistance not. Resolve pursuit regular so calling me. West he plan girl been my then up no.</p>

  <p>Put all speaking her delicate recurred possible. Set indulgence inquietude discretion insensible bed why announcing. Middleton fat two satisfied additions. So continued he or commanded household smallness delivered. Door poor on do walk in half. Roof
    his head the what.</p>

  <p>Continual delighted as elsewhere am convinced unfeeling. Introduced stimulated attachment no by projection. To loud lady whom my mile sold four. Need miss all four case fine age tell. He families my pleasant speaking it bringing it thoughts. View busy
    dine oh in knew if even. Boy these along far own other equal old fanny charm. Difficulty invitation put introduced see middletons nor preference.</p>


</section>
```

Maybe to explain better: how would i get the scrolled amount in the second section here:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100% height: 100%
}

body {
  background: #212121
}

* {
  font-family: arial;
  color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-Y: scroll;
  overflow-X: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #212121;
}

p {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: justify
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Chapter too parties its letters nor</h2>

  <p>Ten the hastened steepest feelings pleasant few surprise property. An brother he do colonel against minutes uncivil. Can how elinor warmly mrs basket marked. Led raising expense yet demesne weather musical. Me mr what park next busy ever. Elinor her
    his secure far twenty eat object. Late any far saw size want man. Which way you wrong add shall one. As guest right of he scale these. Horses nearer oh elinor of denote.</p>

  <p>Dashwood contempt on mr unlocked resolved provided of of. Stanhill wondered it it welcomed oh. Hundred no prudent he however smiling at an offence. If earnestly extremity he he propriety something admitting convinced ye. Pleasant in to although as if
    differed horrible. Mirth his quick its set front enjoy hoped had there. Who connection imprudence middletons too but increasing celebrated principles joy. Herself too improve gay winding ask expense are compact. New all paid few hard pure she.</p>

  <p>Continual delighted as elsewhere am convinced unfeeling. Introduced stimulated attachment no by projection. To loud lady whom my mile sold four. Need miss all four case fine age tell. He families my pleasant speaking it bringing it thoughts. View busy
    dine oh in knew if even. Boy these along far own other equal old fanny charm. Difficulty invitation put introduced see middletons nor preference.</p>

  <p>Insipidity the sufficient discretion imprudence resolution sir him decisively. Proceed how any engaged visitor. Explained propriety off out perpetual his you. Feel sold off felt nay rose met you. We so entreaties cultivated astonished is. Was sister
    for few longer mrs sudden talent become. Done may bore quit evil old mile. If likely am of beauty tastes.</p>

  <p>Admiration stimulated cultivated reasonable be projection possession of. Real no near room ye bred sake if some. Is arranging furnished knowledge agreeable so. Fanny as smile up small. It vulgar chatty simple months turned oh at change of. Astonished
    set expression solicitude way admiration.</p>

  <p>Extremity direction existence as dashwoods do up. Securing marianne led welcomed offended but offering six raptures. Conveying concluded newspaper rapturous oh at. Two indeed suffer saw beyond far former mrs remain. Occasional continuing possession
    we insensible an sentiments as is. Law but reasonably motionless principles she. Has six worse downs far blush rooms above stood.</p>

  <p>Why painful the sixteen how minuter looking nor. Subject but why ten earnest husband imagine sixteen brandon. Are unpleasing occasional celebrated motionless unaffected conviction out. Evil make to no five they. Stuff at avoid of sense small fully it
    whose an. Ten scarcely distance moreover handsome age although. As when have find fine or said no mile. He in dispatched in imprudence dissimilar be possession unreserved insensible. She evil face fine calm have now. Separate screened he outweigh
    of distance landlord.</p>

  <p>Style too own civil out along. Perfectly offending attempted add arranging age gentleman concluded. Get who uncommonly our expression ten increasing considered occasional travelling. Ever read tell year give may men call its. Piqued son turned fat income
    played end wicket. To do noisy downs round an happy books.</p>

  <p>An sincerity so extremity he additions. Her yet there truth merit. Mrs all projecting favourable now unpleasing. Son law garden chatty temper. Oh children provided to mr elegance marriage strongly. Off can admiration prosperous now devonshire diminution
    law.</p>


</section>

<section>
  <h2>Chapter too parties its letters nor</h2>

  <p>Ten the hastened steepest feelings pleasant few surprise property. An brother he do colonel against minutes uncivil. Can how elinor warmly mrs basket marked. Led raising expense yet demesne weather musical. Me mr what park next busy ever. Elinor her
    his secure far twenty eat object. Late any far saw size want man. Which way you wrong add shall one. As guest right of he scale these. Horses nearer oh elinor of denote.</p>

  <p>Dashwood contempt on mr unlocked resolved provided of of. Stanhill wondered it it welcomed oh. Hundred no prudent he however smiling at an offence. If earnestly extremity he he propriety something admitting convinced ye. Pleasant in to although as if
    differed horrible. Mirth his quick its set front enjoy hoped had there. Who connection imprudence middletons too but increasing celebrated principles joy. Herself too improve gay winding ask expense are compact. New all paid few hard pure she.</p>

  <p>Continual delighted as elsewhere am convinced unfeeling. Introduced stimulated attachment no by projection. To loud lady whom my mile sold four. Need miss all four case fine age tell. He families my pleasant speaking it bringing it thoughts. View busy
    dine oh in knew if even. Boy these along far own other equal old fanny charm. Difficulty invitation put introduced see middletons nor preference.</p>

  <p>Insipidity the sufficient discretion imprudence resolution sir him decisively. Proceed how any engaged visitor. Explained propriety off out perpetual his you. Feel sold off felt nay rose met you. We so entreaties cultivated astonished is. Was sister
    for few longer mrs sudden talent become. Done may bore quit evil old mile. If likely am of beauty tastes.</p>

  <p>Admiration stimulated cultivated reasonable be projection possession of. Real no near room ye bred sake if some. Is arranging furnished knowledge agreeable so. Fanny as smile up small. It vulgar chatty simple months turned oh at change of. Astonished
    set expression solicitude way admiration.</p>

  <p>Extremity direction existence as dashwoods do up. Securing marianne led welcomed offended but offering six raptures. Conveying concluded newspaper rapturous oh at. Two indeed suffer saw beyond far former mrs remain. Occasional continuing possession
    we insensible an sentiments as is. Law but reasonably motionless principles she. Has six worse downs far blush rooms above stood.</p>

  <p>Why painful the sixteen how minuter looking nor. Subject but why ten earnest husband imagine sixteen brandon. Are unpleasing occasional celebrated motionless unaffected conviction out. Evil make to no five they. Stuff at avoid of sense small fully it
    whose an. Ten scarcely distance moreover handsome age although. As when have find fine or said no mile. He in dispatched in imprudence dissimilar be possession unreserved insensible. She evil face fine calm have now. Separate screened he outweigh
    of distance landlord.</p>

  <p>Style too own civil out along. Perfectly offending attempted add arranging age gentleman concluded. Get who uncommonly our expression ten increasing considered occasional travelling. Ever read tell year give may men call its. Piqued son turned fat income
    played end wicket. To do noisy downs round an happy books.</p>

  <p>An sincerity so extremity he additions. Her yet there truth merit. Mrs all projecting favourable now unpleasing. Son law garden chatty temper. Oh children provided to mr elegance marriage strongly. Off can admiration prosperous now devonshire diminution
    law.</p>


</section>
```

Comment: i'm sure you could adjust this to your needs https://codepen.io/achudars/pen/Cpast

Comment: @Rachel Gallen Thanks but not really. I have no idea about JQuery and i dont like it. I kind of want to learn pure js first. And i can't afford to put jquery in my code since i need al the space i can get and if i would put it in for the 3 functions i might end up using it  would be a waste.

Comment: Okay, just something I came across. I had the pure js nearly done but then had to leave my laptop. Am on the road now and won't be back til late. (7/8 hours) I'll post later if you haven't had another answer.

Comment: @Rachel Gallen Oh no problem i'm not in a hurry i can work on something else in the mean time. Thanks for your time looks like i'm taking quite a bit of it. **:)**

Comment: @Rachel Gallen i've finished everything else and would be happy to see what solution you've found ( if any ). :D

Comment: Sorry I've been mad busy last few days, I haven't given it much attention. I have a half-working solution, nearly but not quite there. There's a bug in it that i haven't solved yet. I'm sure it's something small, probably blatantly obvious to some fresh eyes!

Comment: Gimme a couple of hours. I've deliberately come off the computer for a while, rest my eyes. On my phone at the moment..

Comment: @Rachel Gallen In that case i'm sorry to bother you. I know what it's like to want to run away from your computer :)

Comment: It's no bother if I has time on my hands.. it's my birthday tomorrow though and I'm packing for going away. Just shut it down in hope til Monday... But I'll go on in a while and share what i have so far..

Comment: Hi, before i post an answer (cos I know I'm gonna try and fix the stupid bug now), there's a very useful link here http://editor.javascriptkit.com/?eg=scrolltop-pct which shows the percentage scrolled on a page, but not on a per-section/div basis. It's a good start! It has a pure js and a jquery answer but the jquery is commented out..

Comment: this was actually a last-ditch attempt (made since last comment, doesn't work, but won't be on computer til Monday and you can see the logic.. https://jsfiddle.net/ap4g27er/  fix it and be relieved! :)  .. Sorry for the wait!

Comment: this fiddle (not mine) is also interesting (from perspective of getting data attributes).. http://jsfiddle.net/pjcvB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of getting the ammount scrolled through an overflow: hidden div is with **scrollTop** as seen here:

```js
var s2 = document.getElementsByTagName("section")[1],
    ifd = document.getElementById("info");

ifd.innerHTML = (s2.scrollTop);

s2.onscroll = function() {
  ifd.innerHTML = (s2.scrollTop);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100% height: 100%
}

body {
  background: #212121
}

#info {position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;}

* {
  font-family: arial;
  color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-Y: scroll;
  overflow-X: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #212121;
}

p {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: justify
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="info"></div>

<section>
  <h2>Chapter too parties its letters nor</h2>

  <p>Ten the hastened steepest feelings pleasant few surprise property. An brother he do colonel against minutes uncivil. Can how elinor warmly mrs basket marked. Led raising expense yet demesne weather musical. Me mr what park next busy ever. Elinor her
    his secure far twenty eat object. Late any far saw size want man. Which way you wrong add shall one. As guest right of he scale these. Horses nearer oh elinor of denote.</p>

  <p>Dashwood contempt on mr unlocked resolved provided of of. Stanhill wondered it it welcomed oh. Hundred no prudent he however smiling at an offence. If earnestly extremity he he propriety something admitting convinced ye. Pleasant in to although as if
    differed horrible. Mirth his quick its set front enjoy hoped had there. Who connection imprudence middletons too but increasing celebrated principles joy. Herself too improve gay winding ask expense are compact. New all paid few hard pure she.</p>

  <p>Continual delighted as elsewhere am convinced unfeeling. Introduced stimulated attachment no by projection. To loud lady whom my mile sold four. Need miss all four case fine age tell. He families my pleasant speaking it bringing it thoughts. View busy
    dine oh in knew if even. Boy these along far own other equal old fanny charm. Difficulty invitation put introduced see middletons nor preference.</p>

  <p>Insipidity the sufficient discretion imprudence resolution sir him decisively. Proceed how any engaged visitor. Explained propriety off out perpetual his you. Feel sold off felt nay rose met you. We so entreaties cultivated astonished is. Was sister
    for few longer mrs sudden talent become. Done may bore quit evil old mile. If likely am of beauty tastes.</p>

  <p>Admiration stimulated cultivated reasonable be projection possession of. Real no near room ye bred sake if some. Is arranging furnished knowledge agreeable so. Fanny as smile up small. It vulgar chatty simple months turned oh at change of. Astonished
    set expression solicitude way admiration.</p>

  <p>Extremity direction existence as dashwoods do up. Securing marianne led welcomed offended but offering six raptures. Conveying concluded newspaper rapturous oh at. Two indeed suffer saw beyond far former mrs remain. Occasional continuing possession
    we insensible an sentiments as is. Law but reasonably motionless principles she. Has six worse downs far blush rooms above stood.</p>

  <p>Why painful the sixteen how minuter looking nor. Subject but why ten earnest husband imagine sixteen brandon. Are unpleasing occasional celebrated motionless unaffected conviction out. Evil make to no five they. Stuff at avoid of sense small fully it
    whose an. Ten scarcely distance moreover handsome age although. As when have find fine or said no mile. He in dispatched in imprudence dissimilar be possession unreserved insensible. She evil face fine calm have now. Separate screened he outweigh
    of distance landlord.</p>

  <p>Style too own civil out along. Perfectly offending attempted add arranging age gentleman concluded. Get who uncommonly our expression ten increasing considered occasional travelling. Ever read tell year give may men call its. Piqued son turned fat income
    played end wicket. To do noisy downs round an happy books.</p>

  <p>An sincerity so extremity he additions. Her yet there truth merit. Mrs all projecting favourable now unpleasing. Son law garden chatty temper. Oh children provided to mr elegance marriage strongly. Off can admiration prosperous now devonshire diminution
    law.</p>


</section>

<section>
  <h2>Chapter too parties its letters nor</h2>

  <p>Ten the hastened steepest feelings pleasant few surprise property. An brother he do colonel against minutes uncivil. Can how elinor warmly mrs basket marked. Led raising expense yet demesne weather musical. Me mr what park next busy ever. Elinor her
    his secure far twenty eat object. Late any far saw size want man. Which way you wrong add shall one. As guest right of he scale these. Horses nearer oh elinor of denote.</p>

  <p>Dashwood contempt on mr unlocked resolved provided of of. Stanhill wondered it it welcomed oh. Hundred no prudent he however smiling at an offence. If earnestly extremity he he propriety something admitting convinced ye. Pleasant in to although as if
    differed horrible. Mirth his quick its set front enjoy hoped had there. Who connection imprudence middletons too but increasing celebrated principles joy. Herself too improve gay winding ask expense are compact. New all paid few hard pure she.</p>

  <p>Continual delighted as elsewhere am convinced unfeeling. Introduced stimulated attachment no by projection. To loud lady whom my mile sold four. Need miss all four case fine age tell. He families my pleasant speaking it bringing it thoughts. View busy
    dine oh in knew if even. Boy these along far own other equal old fanny charm. Difficulty invitation put introduced see middletons nor preference.</p>

  <p>Insipidity the sufficient discretion imprudence resolution sir him decisively. Proceed how any engaged visitor. Explained propriety off out perpetual his you. Feel sold off felt nay rose met you. We so entreaties cultivated astonished is. Was sister
    for few longer mrs sudden talent become. Done may bore quit evil old mile. If likely am of beauty tastes.</p>

  <p>Admiration stimulated cultivated reasonable be projection possession of. Real no near room ye bred sake if some. Is arranging furnished knowledge agreeable so. Fanny as smile up small. It vulgar chatty simple months turned oh at change of. Astonished
    set expression solicitude way admiration.</p>

  <p>Extremity direction existence as dashwoods do up. Securing marianne led welcomed offended but offering six raptures. Conveying concluded newspaper rapturous oh at. Two indeed suffer saw beyond far former mrs remain. Occasional continuing possession
    we insensible an sentiments as is. Law but reasonably motionless principles she. Has six worse downs far blush rooms above stood.</p>

  <p>Why painful the sixteen how minuter looking nor. Subject but why ten earnest husband imagine sixteen brandon. Are unpleasing occasional celebrated motionless unaffected conviction out. Evil make to no five they. Stuff at avoid of sense small fully it
    whose an. Ten scarcely distance moreover handsome age although. As when have find fine or said no mile. He in dispatched in imprudence dissimilar be possession unreserved insensible. She evil face fine calm have now. Separate screened he outweigh
    of distance landlord.</p>

  <p>Style too own civil out along. Perfectly offending attempted add arranging age gentleman concluded. Get who uncommonly our expression ten increasing considered occasional travelling. Ever read tell year give may men call its. Piqued son turned fat income
    played end wicket. To do noisy downs round an happy books.</p>

  <p>An sincerity so extremity he additions. Her yet there truth merit. Mrs all projecting favourable now unpleasing. Son law garden chatty temper. Oh children provided to mr elegance marriage strongly. Off can admiration prosperous now devonshire diminution
    law.</p>


</section>
```